# PHP: Get two arrays from MySQL query table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm capturing the following data from MySQL:

[image: table]

Using PHP, I want to organize the data in two arrays: `'pagamentos'` and `'recebimentos'`, sorted by `'mes'` into a JSON object. Something like:

```
{ name: 'Recebimentos', data: [0.00, 11970.99, 2888.0]}, 
{ name: 'Pagamentos', data: [400.00, 6877.00, 500.00]}
```

I have:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$recebimentos=array();
$pagamentos=array();

        foreach ($rows as $key) {
        if($key['fluxo']=='Recebimentos'){
            array_push($recebimentos, floatval($key['atual']));
        } elseif($key['fluxo']=='Pagamentos'){
            array_push($pagamentos, floatval($key['atual']));
        }
    };

        echo json_encode(array(
            'recebimentos' => array(name=> 'name', data=>$recebimentos),
            'pagamentos' => array(name=> 'name', data=>$pagamentos),
        ));
```

But this is returning:

```
{"recebimentos":{"name":"name","data":[0,11970.99,2888]},"pagamentos":{"name":"name","data":[400,6877,500]}}
```

Comment: It looks like the data is not making it into the recebimentos and pagamentos arrays. Are you sure that this `$recebimentos[]=$key['real'];` is what you want? Wouldn't it be `$recebimentos[]=$key['atual'];`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll edit my question above, since it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two spots that need changes - `$key['real']` should be `$key['atual']` or `$key['actual']`. Not sure if that's a copy-paste error, or if the column is actually named atual:

```
    foreach ($rows as $key) {
        if($key['fluxo']=='Recebimentos'){
            $recebimentos[]=$key['atual'];
        } elseif($key['fluxo']=='Pagamentos'){
            $pagamentos[]==$key['atual'];
        }
    };
```

And when you assign the name of the encoded data, you need the actual name, rather than `'name'`:

```
    echo json_encode(array(
        array(name=> 'recebimentos', data=>$recebimentos),
        array(name=> 'pagamentos', data=>$pagamentos)
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    foreach ($rows as $key) {
        if($key['fluxo']=='Recebimentos'){
            $recebimentos[]=$key['real'];
        } elseif($key['fluxo']=='Pagamentos'){
            $pagamentos[]==$key['real'];
        }
    };
```

by

```
    foreach ($rows as $key) {
        if($key['fluxo']=='Recebimentos'){
            $recebimentos[] = $key['actual']; // 'actual', not 'real'
        } elseif($key['fluxo']=='Pagamentos'){
            $pagamentos[] = $key['actual']; // just 1 '=' and 'actual', not 'real'
        }
    };
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo above, please see my edited question. Thank you